# Testimonials/Reviews for Products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, review

I have my brand website that has 250+ same products, but all have different designs. Basically they all are phone cases, and have designs. I wanted to centralise my system of testimonials/reviews that has to be displayed on all of the product pages.

Basically, it'll be something like 1000+ product reviews inside every product page, and I want the user to be able to input his/her review later-on.

Please can someone guide me through on what should be the best possible way for this?

*Basically, displaying testimonials/reviews will help in better conversion, and is why my thought is stuck there.*

Maybe something like a different section of **Testimonials** in the wp-admin, can help in posting the testimonials, and that will get displayed on every product? As well as a star rating on 5 would help.

Would be glad if someone can assist me with that.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The most frequent approach would be to create a new "review" or "testimonial" [Custom Post Type ("CPT")](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) with a [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) or in your [theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)'s [`functions.php` file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File) (or a new [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Child_Themes)'s `functons.php` file, if your current theme is not custom-built), and then alter your product page [template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates) to use a [secondary loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops) to display your new reviews/testimonials.

All of the documentation I have linked should be enough to get you where you want to go, but there are also a large selection of tutorials available around the 'net.